# Propiedad position afecta a un div que no está en la misma jerarquía en CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, position

He anidado dos divs dentro de otro y les he aplicado position: absolute para que queden encimados, el problema es que todos los divs que pongo ahora, Aunque estén fuera del div padre, se enciman y yo necesito que se muestre por debajo.
ya probé con la propiedad position y aún no obtengo resultados.

La idea es que el DIV .contenedor1 quede por debajo del DIV .contenedor

```css
.contenedor {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .banner{
    width: 97.3%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    
  }

  .banner img{
    margin-left: -1.4%;
    width: 102.76%;
    height: 650px !important;   
  }

  .textos{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 17%;
    width: 100%;
}

.textos h1{
    margin-left: 8%;
    font-family: 'Kiona';
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 32.5px;
}


#hr{
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30.2%;  
    border: 0;
    margin-left: -5%;  
}

#hr1{
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    border: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;    
    
}

.textos p{
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    font-size: 24.5px;
    
    margin-left: 8%;
    
}

.contenedor1{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/banner.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="banner">
             <img src="images/home/fotopag.png" alt="" id="temis">
             </div>
        <div class="textos">
             <h1>Asesoría legal especializada <br> en distintas áreas del Derecho.</h1>
             <br>
             <hr size="4" noshade="noshade" id="hr">
             <hr size="10" noshade="noshade" id="hr1">
             <br>
             <br>
             <p>Desarrollamos soluciones estratégicas e innovadoras <br> para atender con éxito todos tus asuntos legales.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="contenedor1">
    <table>
<tr>
<td>Curso</td>
<td>Nivel</td>
<td>Plataforma</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HTML</td>
<td>Principiante</td>
<td>Aprender desde Cero</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CSS</td>
<td>Avanzado</td>
<td>Aprender desde Cero</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu problema, vos queres que el div 'contenedor1' quede por debajo del div 'contenedor'? yo probe aca y contenedor1 aparece arriba de todo tapando a contenedor es ese tu problema?

Comment: Así es. como dices tú, necesito que el .contenedor1 quede por debajo de .contenedor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu div 'contenedor' no tiene la propiedad `height`, si examinas ese div en la consola no está conteniendo al banner y al texto como debería hacer, además de eso al banner y al texto le das `position: absolute`, hay que tener cuidado con eso porque un elemento que tiene `position: absolute` no reserva espacio en el documento, por lo que otros elementos pueden situarse encima de él.

En resumen: El contenedor no ocupa espacio porque no tiene alto, y los dos elementos que tienen dentro tienen posición absoluta, todo eso contribuye a que el 'contenedor2' ocupe la parte superior de la pantalla.

Supuse que la imagen del banner ocupaba a todo el div 'contenedor' algo así como un fondo para ese div, pero vos modifícalo como necesites:

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.banner{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.banner img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.textos{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.textos h1{
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-family: 'Kiona';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 32.5px;
}


#hr{
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.2%;  
  border: 0;
  margin-left: -5%;  
}

#hr1{
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;    
  
}

.textos p{
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  font-size: 24.5px;
  margin-left: 8%;
  
}

.contenedor1{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
  <title>Hospital XYZ</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="8B1.jpg" alt="" id="temis">
    </div>
    <div class="textos">
      <h1>Asesoría legal especializada <br> en distintas áreas del Derecho.</h1>
      <br>
      <hr size="4" noshade="noshade" id="hr">
      <hr size="10" noshade="noshade" id="hr1">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Desarrollamos soluciones estratégicas e innovadoras <br> para atender con éxito todos tus asuntos legales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Curso</td>
        <td>Nivel</td>
        <td>Plataforma</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>Principiante</td>
        <td>Aprender desde Cero</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>Avanzado</td>
        <td>Aprender desde Cero</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
               
  <script src="scripts2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```